# Is there an easy way to get probability density of normal distribution with the help of numpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I know, I can use my own function like this:

```
def gauss(x, mu, sigma):
    return (2*pi)**(-0.5) * sigma**(-1) * math.exp( - 0.5 * ((x - mu) / sigma)**2)
```

Probably, someone knows what standard numpy or scipy function exists to do the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason this has to use `numpy` instead of `scipy`?  Because `scipy` can do this very easily.

Comment: no reason, scipy is ok too for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scipy`:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
x = np.arange(20)
mu = 5
sigma = 3
mypdf = norm.pdf(x=x, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy to generate a sample from a normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np
mu = 0.0
sigma = 0.1
rand_vector = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (4, 1))
print rand_vector
```

prints:

```
[[-0.0003717 ]
 [ 0.11439928]
 [-0.11803113]
 [ 0.01302493]]
```

Comment: The OP wants to be able to compute the pdf of a normal distribution at various points. You're showing how to generate a *sample* from the normal distribution, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you are correct.  I'll edit to annotate it's a sample.